# getting Illegal mix of collations error

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I have a subdomain system in my application,when i login in my office its login fine but when i login other city or country i am getting this error.

some times working fine and some times not working. suppose if my login id is xyz@india.com when i print this login id i am getting some special characters before login id.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Mysqli_Exception' with message 'Mysqli prepare error: Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is typically caused by comparing two columns where the collation is not compatible.
The [COLLATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collate.html) method will allow you to specify the collation used within the query and thus not return such an error.

If you don’t need any collation and just need to compare you could consider adding “CHARACTER SET BINARY” to the column definition.  This would use the BIN collection set and would allow equals regardless of the connection string or column collation settings.